# MPMoviePlayerController iO7 issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am trying to play a video stored in my application's documents directory through MPMoviePlayerController. I am using the following method to play video:

```
NSArray *directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [directoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
int videoNumber = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"videoSaved"];
NSString* videoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video-%d.mov",videoNumber];
NSString *exportPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath isDirectory:NO];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:exportUrl];
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieDidExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

It works fine on all iOS versions except iOS7. In iOS7 when i try to play video it ives me this error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {    kind = 1;    new = 2;    old = 0;}
```

Comment: @IronManGill you can see i have already user **fileURLWithPath** in **exportURL**

Comment: Try to NSLog the exportUrl

Comment: @Mutawe yeah it gives me the corrent URL
see this: file:///var/mobile/Applications/696925E2-BA2E-4359-AA81-41D98AA594DB/Documents/video-8.mov

Comment: Once i had  the same problem, and i solved by changing the video's name, its a stupid idea but its worked for me

Comment: and try to set:     moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

Comment: @Mutawe i've changed name, but no success. Still same error appearing in log

Comment: @Mutawe thnks for your reply but the second answer also not worked :(

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS i have the same issue and i find many answer but they did not work for me. so how you solved this issue. explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code to this:

```
int videoNumber = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"videoSaved"];

moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video-%d",videoNumber] ofType:@"mov"]]];

moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieDidExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Its crashing and giving me this log: -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer? Did it not work?

Comment: His problem is not related to the answer, its related to the URL